# on iOS device, open app and take screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone, automation, screenshot

I need to "industrialize" screenshot taking on iOS device with a lot of apps.
Everyday, I have to take these screenshots, it's really boring.

For each app, I need to :

1. launch the app
2. wait few seconds to be sure that the app is really loaded
3. emulate button clicking
4. take a screenshot
5. close the app

After that, I need to send these screenshots to my Macbook (but it seems to be simple ..).

This tool could take some screenshots : https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot but, I don't have the apps sources.
Moreover, I can't open Automator on my iPhone (it would be too simple ..).

If you have any ideas to help me ...
Thank you so much!

Comment: Steps 1-4 are the core idea of a clear and safe user experience provided by iOS. Wanting to have another actions flow to take screenshots look like an attempt to develop some kind of spyware and that kind of software won't be accepted (even if you make it work) by the App Store.

Comment: That's a great remark Arthur!
So, the only one solution to proceed to these steps is to include this process in my own applications ?
Thank you for responding.

Comment: Correct. The only automation you can implement is to make a software button (or similar trigger) that captures screenshots and sends to a desired remote location (e.g. DropBox). Always welcome.